# SQL Server WHERE is a date

Tags: sql, sql-server

The assignment is:

Write a `SELECT` statement that returns these columns from the `Orders` table:

- The `OrderID` column
- The `OrderDate` column
- A column named `ApproxShipDate` that’s calculated by adding 2 days to the `OrderDate` column
- The `ShipDate` column
- A column named `DaysToShip` that shows the number of days between the order date and the ship date

When you have this working, add a `WHERE` clause that retrieves just the orders for March 2012.

I have

```
SELECT 
    OrderID, OrderDate,
    DATEADD(DAY, 2, OrderDate) AS ApproxShipDate,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, OrderDate, DATEADD(DAY, 2, OrderDate)) AS DaysToShip
FROM 
    Orders
WHERE
    YEAR('2012') AND MONTH('03');
```

The `YEAR` and `MONTH` are not working. I don't know what is wrong.

I'm using the MyGuitarShop database

Comment: `WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = 2012 AND MONTH(OrderDate) = 3`

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks a ton that was all I needed

Comment: functions in where clause are not sargable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT OrderID,OrderDate,
DATEADD(DAY,2,OrderDate) as ApproxShipDate,
DATEDIFF(DAY,OrderDate,DATEADD(DAY,2,OrderDate)) as DaysToShip
FROM Orders
WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = 2012 AND MONTH(OrderDate) = 3
```

due to @GordonLinoff